# Strange Addition At The End Of .txt File Following fout.write() - Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that will pull variables from a template and effectively Find/Replace into a template.

Example Template:

```
VARIABLES

@username
@password
@secret

###########################################################

My username is @username
Password is @password
Secret is @secret
```

The program will find each variable and ask one by one for user input, opening the file, saving the contents and then closing the file ready for the next variable.

All is working well besides a strange one. Once I have run the code, the end of my text file appears to go a little wild. See below output. As you can see it successfully took the variables and placed them, however it added *"is TESTis TESTetis @secret"* to the end?

```
VARIABLES

User
Pass
TEST

###########################################################

My username is User
Password is Pass
Secret is TESTis TESTis TESTetis @secret
```

I am new to Python (this week) so excuse the code below. I have made it work in my own special way! It may not be the most efficient. Just struggling to see where the extra is being added.

Code:

```
##COPY CONTENTS FROM READ ONLY TO NEW FILE
with open("TestTemplate.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line)
        fin.seek(0)
        fout.seek(0)
        fin.close()
        fout.close()

##PULL VARIABLES AND FIND/REPLACE CONTENTS
with open("out.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("out.txt", "rt") as searchf:
        with open("out.txt", "r+") as fout:
            for line in fin:
                if line.startswith("@"):
                    trimmedLine = line.rstrip()
                    ## USER ENTRY
                    entry = input("Please Enter " + trimmedLine + ": ")
                    for line in searchf:
                        ## ENSURE ONLY VARIABLES AFTER '#' ARE EDITED. KEEPS IT NEAT
                        if trimmedLine in line:
                            fout.write(line.replace(trimmedLine,entry))
                        else:
                            fout.write(line)
                    ##RESET FOCUS TO THE TOP OF THE FILE READY FOR NEXT ITERATION
                    searchf.seek(0)
                    fout.seek(0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `with open(...):` closes the files for you , remove the .close() and seeks(). Also you can shorten it to `with open("TestTemplate.txt", "rt") as fin, open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:` You are opening the same file in different modes at the same time - doesnt this strike you as evil? Its like having 3 ppl cooking in the same pan different foods, one does eggs, the other bacon, the third caramel: _might work out_ - wouldnt like a tast of. open file, read in content into a list of lines, close file. Work your replacements in the list of lines. Open file, output it again. would be much cleaner code.

Comment: Very helpful responses Patrick I appreciate your input. Like I say I am very new to this and there will always be ways of streamlining code. Little tricks like this will help me out greatly in future! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your replacement strings are shorter than the original template place holders, resulting in leftover characters after you perform file seek. You should truncate the file before you call `seek()` so that the extra character at the end can be trimmed.

```
##RESET FOCUS TO THE TOP OF THE FILE READY FOR NEXT ITERATION
searchf.seek(0)
fout.truncate()
fout.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the same file (out.txt) in different modes at the same time - doesn't this strike you as evil? *It is like having 3 people cooking in the same pan. One does eggs, one bacon, the third caramel: might work out - wouldnt like to taste it.*

Cleaner code [IPO-Model (yeah its old, but still valid)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model):

- Open file, read in content, close file.
- Do your replacements.
- Open output file, write replaced text, close file.

Shorter version of reading files:

```
with open("TestTemplate.txt", "rt") as fin,
     open("out.txt", "wt") as fout:
        text = fin.read() # read in text from template

        fout.write(text)  # you could simply use module os and copy() the file ...
                          # or simply skip copying here and use open("out.txt","w") below
```

Using a fixed text here - you could aquire it as above:

```
text = """VARIABLES

@username
@password
@secret

###########################################################

My username is @username
Password is @password
Secret is @secret"""        

replaceMe = {} # dictionary to hold the to be replaced parts and its replacement

# go through all lines
for l in text.splitlines():
    if l.startswith("@"): # if it starts with @, ask for content top replace it with
        replaceMe[l.rstrip()] = input("Please Enter {}:".format(l.rstrip()))

newtext = text
# loop over all keys in dict, replace key in text
for k in replaceMe:
    newtext = newtext.replace(k,replaceMe[k])

print(text)
print(newtext)

# save changes - using "w" so you can skip copying the file further up
with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Output after replacement:

```
VARIABLES

a
b
c

###########################################################

My username is a
Password is b
Secret is c
```